# Efficient alternative to Map<Integer, Integer> in Java, with regards to autoboxing?

Tags: java, android, linkedhashmap, autoboxing, unboxing

I'm using a `LinkedHashMap<Integer, Integer>` to store values of layers on a tile in a 2D game. Higher numbers are drawn over the lower numbers.

In my draw function, I iterate through the value set and draw each one. This means I'm unboxing values `(width * height * numLayers)` times. I'm planning to port to Android so I want to be as efficient as possible, and I'm thinking this is too much?

The reason I'm using a Map is because the layer number (key) matters: keys above 4 are drawn over players, etc.. So I'll frequently need to skip over a bunch of keys.

I could probably just use an `int[10]` since I won't need that many layers, but then all of the unused layers would each be taking up 32 bits over nothing, compared to my current HashMap which can have keys 0, 9 and only take up 64 bits.

Comment: *Unboxing* is very efficient - all it's doing is getting a number out of an object. It doesn't create a new object or anything. Do you have any evidence that this is actually causing you a problem?

Comment: I'm doing a fair amount of boxing too, since I keep chunks of 2000 tiles loaded at any given time. That's more of a memory issue than a performance issue though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Efficient alternative to Map ?

`SparseIntArrays` is more efficient than `HashMap<Integer,Integer>`. According to documentation

> SparseIntArrays map integers to integers. Unlike a normal array of
>   integers, there can be gaps in the indices. It is intended to be more
>   memory efficient than using a HashMap to map Integers to Integers,
>   both because it avoids auto-boxing keys and values and its data
>   structure doesn't rely on an extra entry object for each mapping. For containers holding up to hundreds of items, the performance difference is not significant, less than 50%.

for more reference [click here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseIntArray.html)
**For Non-Android languages** :

- Write your own Hash-based map class (not implementing collections.Map). Relatively simple using a 'linear probe' in an array of cells -- the other technique is a linked-list, which (again) will be as large as the 'direct array' option.
- [GNU Trove has primitive maps](http://trove.starlight-systems.com/) that will do what you want. But if you are not trying to eke out every byte of memory, I'd second Thomas's suggestion to just use an array.

Comment: Thank you for the response, that sounds perfect. This application is for desktop too, will I still be able to use it?

Comment: No this class is available in android.util so it only available for android

Comment: It's no longer perfect since I can't use this class on desktop, but I found the source code and I'll use it as a reference to make my own class. The source is here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/0b285499db739ba50f2f839d633e763c70e67f96/core/java/android/util/SparseIntArray.java